# How to read an image file from ftp and convert it into an opencv image without saving in python

Tags: python, opencv, ftplib

The question is self explanatory, basically I want to read an image file from ftp using ftplib and convert it into an opencv image but without saving it on the disk in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this myself using the following code.

```
connection= ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
r = BytesIO()
connection.retrbinary('RETR '+ image_path, r.write)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(r.getvalue()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv.imdecode(image, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: consider import io and call io.BytesIO()